# Drag UIScrollView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa

I've got a outer scrollview inside an inner scrollview. I would like to scroll the outer scrollview until the content offset is at some point and then continue the drag inside the inner scrollview.

I've got it to work with toggling `scrollEnabled` on both scrollviews inside `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate. The only problem now that I've to release my finger before the '**next**' drag is registered on the inner scrollview (and other way around of course). Is it possible to continue my drag inside another scroll view?

Comment: Why do you need two scrollviews? Surely just one scroll view will do the trick?

Comment: I agree with @Fogmeister. You can use the y offset to determine how far down you have dragged the containing ScrollView